# I want to make my rails app read qr codes but an error that undefined method `read' for #<ChunkyPNG::Image:> occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code, rmagick

```
p  ZBar::Image.from_jpeg(qrcode_tag("hello")).process

 def qrcode_tag(text)
     qr = ::RQRCode::QRCode.new(text).as_png
     image = Magick::Image.from_blob((qr).read).first
     image.format = 'JPEG'
     return image
 end
```

As I know, RQRCode doesn't support png file type, so I tried to convert a qr code that its file type is png to jpeg then an error that I indicated occurred.

Answer (score 0):

`ChunkyPNG::Image` does not provide a read method. You probably want to call `to_datastream` on it. See the documentation of the `chunky_png` gem: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wvanbergen/chunky_png/ChunkyPNG/Image